# erlang on google app engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, erlang

I know python can be run on GAE

1. what is different erlang and python in lay man term?
2. can erlang run on google app engine ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Erlang and Python are programming languages, and each language has one or more "runtimes" that allow you to run programs written in those languages. GAE supplies a Python runtime.

GAE has no support for Erlang programs.

Comment: Good answer.  GAE also has a Java runtime, which has opened up GAE to many of Jave Virtual Machine languages (JRuby, Groovy, Clojure, even a form of PHP). If you want something similar to Erlang on the JVM, you might want to look into Scala.