# Custom runtime for non-flexible environment app?

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, erlang

I don't think that my gae python app has a flexible environment because I created it many years ago. Now I want to try and create a module that has another runtime than python and keep the python app running python alongside a new runtime, custom or just another. Maybe mix PHP and python or similar. I don't need it but I want to learn and explore the possibilities. I'm also interested in learning Erlang and deploy Erlang code with appengine. I see there is questions about it already

[erlang on google app engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1654759/erlang-on-google-app-engine)

And [issue 125 in the tracker](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=125#makechanges).

But how should we actually do it? If we make our own runtime provided that is allowed.

My app.yaml looks like

```
application: montaoproject
version: newsearch
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true
module: default
instance_class: F1
automatic_scaling:
  min_idle_instances: 5
  max_idle_instances: automatic
  min_pending_latency: automatic
  max_pending_latency: 30ms
  max_concurrent_requests: 50

default_expiration: "14d 5h"

env_variables:
  GAE_USE_MONTAO : 'anyvalue'
  KOOL_VERSION : '17a'

includes:
- br.yaml # Brazil
- in.yaml # India
- us.yaml # USA
- pk.yaml
- search.yaml # search pages
- admin.yaml # admin pages
- providers.yaml # auth providers
- statics.yaml # static content

handlers:
- url: /(business|ai|newindia|insert-ad.html)
  script: montao.app

- url: /blobview.*
  script: kool_update.app
  login: admin

- url: /market.*
  script: main.app

- url: /
  script: montao.app

- url: /(index.html|sign-up.html|login.html)
  script: montao.app

- url: /(login.*|login|googlogin|googlogout|create/)
  script: login.app

- url: /(customer_service.htm|contactfileupload|support.html|faq.html)
  script: customer_service.app

- url: /stats.*
  script: google.appengine.ext.appstats.ui.app

# All other URLs use main.app
- url: /.*
  script: main.app

inbound_services:
- mail

builtins:
- remote_api: on
- deferred: on
#- appstats: on

error_handlers:
  - file: default_error.html

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: latest
- name: jinja2
  version: latest
- name: setuptools
  version: latest
- name: markupsafe
  version: latest
- name: django
  version: latest
- name: PIL
  version: latest
- name: webob
  version: latest
- name: lxml
  version: latest
- name: ssl
  version: latest
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your `app.yaml` file is a standard env one (it doesn't have `vm:true` or `env:flex` in it).

Yes, it's possible to mix and match services/modules in different languages and with different environments inside the same app. You can even switch the language and environment of the *same* module in a different *version* of that module. That's because modules offer complete code isolation, see [Comparison of service isolation and project isolation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/microservices-on-app-engine#comparison_of_service_isolation_and_project_isolation). Related post: [Upload a Java and node.js project to Google AppEngine at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42413211/upload-a-java-and-node-js-project-to-google-appengine-at-once/42418452#42418452)

I always try to structure a multi-service/module app with each service in its own subdir, as described in [Can a default service/module in a Google App Engine app be a sibling of a non-default one in terms of folder structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34110178/can-a-default-service-module-in-a-google-app-engine-app-be-a-sibling-of-a-non-de/34111170#34111170)

So first I'd create a `default` subdirectory of your app dir and move all your existing `default` module specific files into it, with the exception of the app-level config, which I'd keep at the top level and symlink inside the `default` dir as described in that post. Then I'd verify that the `default` module still works as expected.

Then I'd create a new subdirectory for every new module I need to add and add the code for it as needed.

**Side note:** sharing code via symlinks as described in the post mentioned above works for standard env modules, but it probably doesn't work with flexible ones, see [Sharing code between modules in a GAE project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42464203/sharing-code-between-modules-in-a-gae-project/42465117#42465117)